# Need to find and replace a particular word in a text file based on lookup

Tags: python-2.7

```
f = open("info.txt",'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

newdata = filedata.replace("opdut_decoded.wav","a88.wav")

f = open("info.txt",'w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()
```

This is my example code to replace one word only.

I need to find a word from an text file and replace/rename that word from an another text file line by line by lookup words.

Ex: searching a word "search" and replace("1") the word from another first line/word of a text file.

It's  needs to be continue for multiple line rename.
Is there is any way available in python.Can you Please guide me.

Comment: For Example: I have a text file with lines of "xxxxxxxxxx opdut_decoded" .same word for all lines in that text file. And i have another text file with lines "example1" ,"example2" , "example3" like that in line by line. Here i need to find the word "opdut_decoded" in first text file and rename it to first line of a second text file accordingly.Similarly need to rename all the lines by using second text file lines.Here "xxxxxxxxx" means sone text in front of "opdut_decoded"

Comment: Can you share any details